# Missing Google Assistant Voices

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I was going to check out the new Google Assistant voices, but I am only to see the default female voice as an option.

My language is set to English (U.S.), I'm located in the U.S., and my system is above android 6.0 (7.0 on Droid Turbo 2), so what am I missing?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtukQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

They were available this past weekend but they're missing now. Others on Reddit have mentioned the same thing. Must be an update. Hopefully just a bug issue being fixed ASAP.